# how could i verify whether i am creating a new instance of my object every time?

Tags: javascript

How to check if i am creating a `new instance` of the `object`?.

```
(function($, window, document,undefind){
    var Yahoo = {
    }
    $.fn.queryTwitter = function(){
        this.each(function(){
            //$(this).text(Yahoo.name);
            // How to check if here if its a new instance of Yahoo object
        });
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.queryTwitter.options = {

    }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

The below code would create `new instance of Yahoo object` every time. But in my case i am using an object literal, i could use `Object.create(yahoo);`. **But how could i verify whether i am creating a new instance of my object every time?.**

```
function Yahoo (){    
}    
new Yahoo();
```

Comment: If it's a literal, you surely aren't creating any instances ?

Comment: `instance1 === instance2` would work no?

Comment: What do you mean by "verify"? *What* would be a new instance? Newer than what? Don't you know wheter you use `new`, `Object.create` to instantiate objects or whether you the same object literal over and over?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, this would be a way:

```
(function($, window, document,undefind){
    var originalYahoo = Yahoo = {};
    $.fn.queryTwitter = function(){
        this.each(function(){
            if(Yahoo !== originalYahoo) alert("New Instance!");
            ...   
        });
        return this;
    };
    ...
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Cheers